# Running Python Script when opening MXD?

Tags: arcpy, excel, mxd, python-addin

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

I want a Python script to run on opening the MXD which would pull an excel worksheet into a GDB and refresh the map.

I only want this to happen in this specific MXD.

Answer (score 14):

If you are going to ArcMap 10.1 you could create a python add-in. The add-in gives you access to an "on open" function that will run code when you open the mxd.

The help [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000018000000) explains how to create one and has a sample that adds a base layer to the mxd when opening.

Answer (score 5):

You could code within the VBA of the mxd and call the python script within the code wrapper below:

```
Private Function MxDocument_OpenDocument() As Boolean

End Function
```

Comment: Good Question. A possible continuation to artwork21's answer can be found [Here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=107538) but I haven't tried it yet - it's a bit of a workaround, but it sounds promising.

Answer (score 3):

In 10.0, you could use VBA as in [artwork21's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/10809/115), or write a very simple ArcMap [add-in](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000w2000000) using ArcObjects to run a script tool or shell out to arbitrary executables/scripts on startup, as in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/28196/753).

It would probably be worth waiting for 10.1's [Python add-ins](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000025000000) if you don't want to write an ArcObjects add-in specifically for this.