# Python: Run script when opening an MXD in ArcGIS 10

Tags: python, arcmap

This post is related to
[Running Python Script when opening MXD?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10776/run-a-python-script-when-opening-an-mxd)

I would like a python script to run every time a .mxd is opened. However, the link above uses VBA to do it, which ESRI suggests migrating away from....

http://events.esri.com/uc/QandA/index.cfm?fuseaction=answer&conferenceId=2F6DC1A1-1422-2418-883C3868A9004888&questionId=3182

I am looking for way to do it with python.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stick with VBA in 10.0 as it's the only way to (easily) do it, 10.1 has [Python Add-Ins](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/application_extension/014p00000018000000/) which will let you [run Python when you open a document](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Application_Extension/014p00000019000000/) (`newDocument`, `openDocument` events).

Comment: Links in answer are broken but I found what I needed to do this [**here**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000018000000).