# Running ArcPy script from ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

the standard method requires to run ArcPy script in command line, i've struggled with it to run but without a result, i can `import arcpy`, set the workspace to the geodatabase path and describe the env variable using `arcpy.Describe(arcpy.env.workspace).name` it gives me the geodatabase name, but when i try to get featureclasses using `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` i get `[]`, i have made sure that all the environement variables in PATH and PYTHONPATH are ok .

i would like to know if there's an alternative way to run ArcPy script, like it could be run in ArcMap console, is there a way to send scripts to ArcMap console using ArcObjects, what's the difference between ArcMap console and standard command line console?

so any way to run an ArcPy script using ArcObjects 10 or Arcgis Engine 10 will be very welcome.

Comment: I suggest you get the Python script working by itself first before trying to call it from another environment.

Comment: i've tested Arcpy script in Arcmap console, it works like expected in arcmap, but in commande line console, it do not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be several options. If you package your script into a toolbox you could reference your toolbox (and tool) via ArcObjects as such:

```
 IGeoProcessor2 gp = new GeoProcessorClass();
 gp.AddToolbox(@"C:\YourPath\YourToolbox.tbx");
 parameters.Add(@"C:\YourPath\ParamsIfYouHaveThem.gdb\ParamFC");
 gp.Execute("NameOfYourToolInsideReferencedToolbox", parameters, null);
```

Read more on this method here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#executingCustomTool

Or you could try this route:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\path\toYour\script.py";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.Start()
```

which is mentioned here: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=276632

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, i've tested the second solution, it uses system shell so the problem persists, i had'nt worked, concerning the first choice i need some time to create a toolbox and test it again.

Comment: I've personally used the former with success, so I can vouch for that. The latter is one I haven't tried so I can't speak to it efficacy firsthand. Let me know if you have any question about the former method.

Comment: it WORKS LIKE A CHARM, thanks a lot. i hope i could run all arcpy scripts by this way.

Comment: this link could help for creating script based tool http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_creating_script_tools/001500000006000000/

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to execute arcpy.ListFeatureClasses to get a list of featureclasses in your geodatabase.

Comment: This is correct, [ListDatasets](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001m000000) lists Feature Datasets but not Feature Classes. The terminology is unfortunate of course, but a feature dataset is a container for feature classes -- ESRI doesn't use consistent terminology when they use the term dataset. Sometimes it means a container, sometimes it means an individual table/feature class.

Comment: thanks i've made an edit, but in despite of using `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` i get an empty array, but in ArcMap console i get all the featureclasses `[u'new_dir_sj', u'new_dir6', u'dir_buf', u'div_riv']`