# Executing Python script from .NET AddIn and also write its standard output and geoprocessor messages to ArcMap Python Window?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, add-in, python-window

Can a Python script be executed from a .NET AddIn and also write its standard output and geoprocessor message to the ArcMap Python Window?

I have no problem call python scripts with Process.Start or GeoProcessorClass.Execute.  But I have an existing AddIn (10.1) and I want to add a new button that will call the python script and have it behave the same way a right-click `Load...` behaves in the ArcMap python window.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm currently using **[this procedure](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/28196/31)**.

And it does run the script--I'm just after the same out to the python window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The .Net parts of your code can't talk to the Python window.

Comment: Years ago I tried to see if I could import arcgisscripting into IronPython (Python's .NET version) - Fail :(  I never tried with ArcPy and don't have a version to hand.  It's not likely... but who knows... worth a try for all of the 5 seconds it would take?

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own logging window. See the [Simple logging dockable window with a custom context menu](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/00010000048s000000.htm) sample for a starting point. From there you would need to simply get the messages from your GP result object and add them to the log window.