# How to create ArcSDE Geodatabase in PostgreSQL without ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcobjects, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase

I am programming a small application using Arcobjects, and I need to create an ArcSDE geodatabase on PostgreSQL.

In ArcSDE at 10.2 there is no Post Installation Wizard.

How do I create a Geodatabase in PostgreSQL using ArcSDE line Command? i.e. without needing to use ArcGIS Desktop (Create Entreprise Geodatabase toolbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ArcSDE Administration Command Reference:

> **Beginning with ArcGIS 10.1, you must use a geoprocessing tool or
>   Python script to create a geodatabase**. For geodatabases in Oracle, SQL
>   Server, and **PostgreSQL**, if you can use the default settings, use
>   the Create Enterprise Geodatabase tool or a Python script that calls
>   this tool.  If you want to configure your database before creating a
>   geodatabase, use the Enable Enterprise Geodatabase tool or a Python
>   script that calls this tool.

Which means you cannot create a geodatabase with ArcSDE command line tools, you have to use ArcGIS Desktop or Engine Developer Kit with Python installed (which will give you access to the arcpy). You can still use the ArcSDE cmd to create an ArcSDE Windows service.

Comment: thanks for your help.so i have to use engine developer kit but i dont know how to run python script on arcobject

Comment: Haven't done that, but some did: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28191/running-arcpy-script-from-arcobjects. The help is here: Leveraging ArcPy in a .NET application (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/Leveraging_ArcPy_in_a_NET_application/000100000m0s000000/). You could also just run the GP tool create enterprise gdb from ArcObjects: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/Sample_Executing_geoprocessing_tools/000100000161000000/